# How can I pass HTML tags text into a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

How can I pass all the tags text into the variable job? I tried the below but i doesn't work.

```js
var pp = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, p");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < pp.length; i++) {
  var job = encodeURIComponent(pp[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Tags, or elements? The former are text (strings) in a file. The latter are DOM nodes. Which are you after?

Comment: Also, your variable assignment overwrites itself with every cycle of the for loop. That doesn't seem useful.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What does this code do and how does that compare to what you expect it to do?  What do you see if you `console.log(job);` in your `for` loop?

Comment: `var job = []` outside the loop and `job.push(pp[i].innerHTML)` inside the loop. Is this what you're trying to do? Not sure why you want to `encodeURIComponent` here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm after the HTML tags: h1, h2, h3, p. I want to pass their innerHTML into the variable job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*....How can I pass all the tags text into the variable job*

You can use map to get all element's text in an array:

```js
var pp = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, p");
var job = Array.from(pp).map(el => el.textContent);
console.log(job);
```

```html
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h2>This is h2</h2>
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<p>This is paragrap</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the encoded text by spreading the `NodeList` that gets returned from the query.

```js
const jobs = [...document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, p')]
  .map(el => encodeURIComponent(el.innerHTML));

console.log(jobs);
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, p { display: none; }

.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<h1>&</h1>
<h2>#</h2>
<h3>$</h3>
<p>@</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and joining the resulting array into a string

```js
var pp = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, p");

var job = [...pp].map(elm => encodeURIComponent(elm.innerHTML)).join(' ');

console.log(job);
```

```html
<h1>h1&</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<p>p</p>
```